# Automatically selecting tab upon redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am running a ruby on rails website and it currently supports javascript an jquery. I am using htmlslim, scss, and bootstrap.

I am wondering it if is possible to have a button or link that sends a user to another page, then automatically clicks on a tab on that page.

For instance I have a page with the following compiled html:

```
...
<div class="row">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs profile-tabs" id="userTabs">
    <li class="active" id="userItems" role="presentation">
      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#items" role="tab">
        <span class="key">Items</span>
        <span class="value">13</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
      <a class="stand-card-activate" data-toggle="tab" href="#people" role="tab">
        <span class="key">People</span>
        <span class="value">3</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
...
```

This is a row with 2 tabs and the Items tab is the tab that is by default selected when the user visits the page.

Is there some way to make a button that can link to this page and have the People tab automatically selected?

Here is the same code in slim:

```
  ...
  .row
    ul#userTabs.nav.nav-tabs.profile-tabs
      li#userItems.active[role="presentation"]
        a(href="#items" role="tab" data-toggle="tab")
          span.key Items
          span.value = @user.items.count
      li(role="presentation")
        a.stand-card-activate(href="#people" role="tab" data-toggle="tab")
          span.key people
          span.value = @people_count
    ...
```

EDIT 2:
Code so far:

slim:

```
a.back-to-user-people-btn.pull-left(href=www.yourpage.com/#people) Back to People
```

JS:

```
var hash= window.location.hash;
  if(hash.length > 0 ) {
    $('a[role="tab"]').parent().removeClass('active');//remove the default active tab
    $('a[href="'+hash+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
  }
```

This jquery allows it to have the correct tab name highlighted and "active" but the contents of the items tab is still the content that the user sees.

EDIT 3: Show tab contents slim code

```
.tab-content
    #items.tab-pane.fade.active.in.col-md-12(arialabelledby="items" role="tabpanel")
      .card-container = render partial: 'partials/item', collection: @user[:items], as: :user_item, locals: {user: @user}

    #people.tab-pane.fade.active.in.col-md-12(arialabelledby="people" role="tabpanel")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

a link should look like : www.yourpage.com/#tabhrefid

When the page is loaded it will take the hash from the url and add the class active to the tab witch has the link with the same href

```
  $(function(){
      var hash= window.location.hash;
          if(hash.length > 0 ) {
              $('a[role="tab"]').parent().removeClass('active');//remove the default active tab
              $('a[href="'+hash+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
              $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
              $(hash).addClass('active');
           }
    });
```

Comment: I can't really understand exactly how this would operate. Would that Jquery activate upon the page with tabs loading?

Comment: This does work in that it highlights the correct link, but it does not activate the tab contents below it. So, it does not simulate a click. I will keep working with what you gave me and if it leads to an answer ill accept it and edit your answer with the extra code needed/